# Tooltip not visible

Tags: javascript, tooltip

Hi I am having an insanely hard time with my JavaScript code in debugging the tooltip. In the console I can see in the elements and console it is populating with information and updating but nothing is visible. Thank you so much for your help!

I have tried everything and thus far nothing has been successful if anyone has any fresh ideas or thoughts to try that would be great!

```
//TOOLTIP
    let tooltipGroup = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "tooltip")
        .style("display", "block");

// Add vertical line to tooltip
    tooltipGroup.append("line")
        .attr("class", "tooltip-line")
        .attr("y1", 0)
        .attr("y2", height);

// Add tooltip text for the population
    tooltipGroup.append("text")
        .attr("class", "tooltip-population")
        .attr("y", "-1.5em")  // Offset from the tooltip line
        .attr("x", "5px");    // Offset from the tooltip line

// Add tooltip text for the date
    tooltipGroup.append("text")
        .attr("class", "tooltip-date")
        .attr("y", "-0.5em")  // Offset from the population text
        .attr("x", "5px");    // Offset from the tooltip line

    svg.append("rect")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("pointer-events", "all")
        .on("mouseover", () => {
            console.log("Rectangle Mouse over triggered");
            tooltipGroup.style("display", "block")
        })
        .on("mouseout", () => {
            console.log("Rectangle Mouse out triggered");
            // tooltipGroup.style("display", "none")
        })
        .on("mousemove", mousemove);


    let bisectDate = d3.bisector(d => d.date).left;

    function mousemove(event) {
        console.log("mousemove function called");

        // Get x position of mouse
        let x0 = xScale.invert(d3.pointer(event)[0]);

        // Use bisector to get index of closest date
        let i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1);
        console.log("Index from bisector:", i);

        //use index form previous to grab the data element at the location
        let d0 = data[i - 1];
        let d1 = data[i];
        let d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0;

        // Shift the tooltip group to the mouse position
        tooltipGroup.attr("transform", `translate(${xScale(d.date)},0)`);

        // Update the tooltip text
        tooltipGroup.select(".tooltip-population").text(`Population: ${d.population}`);
        tooltipGroup.select(".tooltip-date").text(d3.timeFormat("%B %Y")(d.date));


    }
    // Test Tooltip Display (positioning it in the middle for debugging)
    tooltipGroup.style("display", "block");
    tooltipGroup.attr("transform", `translate(${width / 2},0)`); // position in the middle of the SVG

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Share your full code

Comment: I don't think I can unfortunately on StackOverflow I tried. I am pretty annoyed I have tried fixing it for like two days now for my HW.

Comment: If it is possible to share all the code please let me know but I don't think I can...